# tablesorter pagination makes table rows unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tablesorter

I am have a problem using tablesorter pagination plugin. The table rows is clickable when I first generate the page, but after I goes to next/prev page, create a new table, or sort the table, whatever ways I modified the table, the rows become unclickable.

How to solve this problem?

My code is in this jsFiddle here 
http://jsfiddle.net/hxKG3/

It is a sliding Panel, you can click the "variable" trigger to bring up the table.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I've changed in your fiddle and it seems to work

```
$('table.tablesorter tbody tr').live('click',function(event) {
```

But be aware that 'live' is being deprecated, you should be using

```
$('table.tablesorter tbody tr').on('click',function(event) {
```

, witch also doesn't work with tablesorter.

I guess it's because tablesorter has some years and it is not fully compatible with jquery 1.7.2

Comment: +1 nice answer, but the reason is actually that the pager completely removes invisible rows from the table for faster sorting.

Comment: @fudgey Thanks for mentioning that. Is it possible to suppress tablesorter for removing invisible rows. Since it makes things became very tricky. I am having a hard time because of this behavior.

Comment: If you guys can take a look at my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873652/how-to-uncheck-all-the-checkbox-in-tablesorter-with-pagination-functionality would be so great. Thank you.

Comment: @SongtaoZ Check out my fork of [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html) on Github. I have added an option to the pager addon to prevent it from removing the rows (`removeRows:false`), in case you are interested.